# Which Mahavishnu/Vishnu is giving five verses eternal knowledge to lord Brahma in the Brahma-samhita chapter five?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

Everyone in the ISKCON and Gaudiya Brahman spiritual sect knows about Brahma-samhita and the importance of the Shastra, right from Krishna-Chaitanya, Sril Jiva Gosvami, Bhaktisiddhanta Svami maharaj, so on and so forth.

At the end of the fifth chapter (sixty two verses), we find the "panch-sloki vijnana", the five versed knowledge. Krishna (thru Gayatri) is passing on  the eternal knowledge to Lord Brahma. The question comes on our minds, which Mahavishnu/vishnu, mentioned in the verse, "atho uvaach mahavishnu....". ?? [The Causal Maha-vishnu (Karnodasayi Vishnu) or the Radical Mool-Vishnu (Garbhodsayi Vishnu) ??]

https://vedabase.net/bs/5/57/en

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: "athaato brahman jijnasa" !!

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is seen from the translation of the verse itself:
https://vedabase.io/en/library/bs/5/57/

> Śrī brahma-saṁhitā 5.57
>
> athovāca mahā-viṣṇur bhagavantaṁ prajāpatim brahman mahattva-vijñāne
> prajā-sarge ca cen matiḥ pañca-ślokīm imāṁ vidyāṁ vatsa dattāṁ nibodha
> me
>
> Synonyms
>
> atha — then; uvāca — said; mahā-viṣṇuḥ — the Supreme Lord; bhagavantam
> — unto the glorious; prajāpatim — Lord Brahmā; brahman — O Brahmā;
> mahattva — of the glory (of Godhead); vijñāne — in real knowledge;
> prajā-sarge — in creating offspring; ca — and; cet — if; matiḥ — the
> inclination; pañca-ślokīm — five ślokas; imām — this; vidyām —
> science; vatsa — O beloved; dattām — given; nibodha — hear; me — from
> Me.
>
> Translation
>
> On hearing these hymns containing the essence of the
> truth, the Supreme **Lord Kṛṣṇa said to Brahmā**, "Brahmā, if you
> experience the inclination to create offspring by being endowed with
> the real knowledge of the glory of Godhead, listen, My beloved, from
> Me to this science set forth in the following five ślokas.

So it was Lord Krishna who is called as *mahā-viṣṇur* in the verse, its him who spoke those verses to Brahma. Nothing unusual about that. Lord Krishna can be called as Maha Vishnu, or just as Vishnu because He really is none other than Lord Vishnu himself. In Hindu scriptures we can find many examples where Lord Krishna is called with various names Vishnu, Vasudeva, Keshava, etc.

Comment: Ok. But "ekoham bahusyam", is an eternal fact applicable everywhere!! Krishna is "Adipurusham", eternal primeval cause of every cause. Krishna is everywhere but He is always present in His transcendental realms too.